# Is there a way to list reserved words in terraform?

Tags: terraform

In Python, I can list all keywords with `python -c "import keyword;print(keyword.kwlist)"` Is there a way to get the reserved words in `terraform`?

Comment: [_There are no globally-reserved words, but in some contexts certain identifiers are reserved to function as keywords. These are discussed further in the relevant documentation sections that follow. In such situations, the identifier's role as a keyword supersedes any other valid interpretation that may be possible. Outside of these specific situations, the keywords have no special meaning and are interpreted as regular identifiers._](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/main/hclsyntax/spec.md#keywords)